# how to perform a function in the end other script?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide **div id="FormStep"** when will be check last input.

***On my page I use this HTML code:***

```
<div id="FormStep">
  <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" class="validate" />
  <div id="Checktest1Input"></div>
  <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" class="validate" />
  <div id="Checktest2Input"></div>
  <input type="text" name="test3" id="test3" class="validate" />
  <div id="Checktest3Input"></div>
<input type="button" id="Step" value="Send"/>
</div>
```

***For validation on the page I use this JS code:***

```
$('#Step').on('click',function(){
    $('.validate').each(function(){

        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
        $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('false');
          return false;
        } else {
        $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('true');
        }

      });
});
```

**Tell me please how I can add code `$('#Step').hide();` that this code `$('#Step').hide();` perform after check last input?**

Comment: Are you looking to hide the `#step` for any validation error or only if the last entry is invalid?

Comment: Do you need to show error messages for the remaining inputs if one of them fails validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrdFy/)

```
$('#Step').on('click',function(){
    var hideStep = true;
    $('.validate').each(function(){

        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
        $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('false');
          hideStep = false;
          return false;
        } else {
        $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('true');
        }
      });
    if (hideStep)
      $('#Step').hide();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't validate the remaining elements if one fails, due to the `return false` being part of the loop.

Comment: Neither does the OP's code which is where the `return false;` is taken from.  I've assumed this is the behaviour required.

Comment: Fair enough, I've asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified significantly by using:

```
$('#Step').on('click',function(){
    var valid = true;
    $('.validate').each(function(){
        valid = valid && $(this).val().length != 0;
        $(this).next().html("" + ($(this).val().length != 0)); 
    });
    if(valid){
        $(this).hide();
    }
    return valid;
});
```

Comment: This would hide the step regardless of whether the validation passed

Comment: @PassKit Yes, but that isn't described anywhere in the question. The question simply asks how to hide the element after the last input is checked, which is what my answer does.

Comment: @PassKit Nevertheless, I've added a check that only hides the button if validation fails.

Comment: @LeoLoki Made a mistake. Try it now.

Comment: @Asad your code check all input in one time and show all errors at once. On my code you can see sequence. On start check first element, if him value empty, than show error(once). then if value first input not empty script check second input value and etc... Your code other...

Comment: Yes, Asad's code other ..... and better! User is informed of all errors, at once, not one at a time === good UI design.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable and set $('#Step').hide(); after the each function:

```
$('#Step').on('click',function(){
    var error = false;
    $('.validate').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
          $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('false');
          error = false;
        } else {
          $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('true');
          error = true;
        }
      });
    if(!error) { 
      $('#Step').hide();
    }
});
```

.each is synchronious which means everything below the .each function will be loaded after it ran.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to hide the action is there is a invalid input

```
$('#Step').on('click',function(){
    var valid = true;
    $('.validate').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('false');
          valid = false;
        } else {
            $('#Check'+this.id+'Input').html('true');
        }
      });
    if(!valid){
        $('#Step').hide();
    }
});
```